# My blog has a design issue.

Tags: widgets, blog, design, blogger

My blog  has been getting a good visitors these days. I have used linkwithin add ons to show related posts. But the problem is it is showing related posts in even homepage. Is there any way to not to show it in homepage?

Comment: Look at the [`is_home`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) and the [`is_front_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) conditionals.

Comment: Please provide a link to plugin in question if it depends on it for context.